# Swift - Fatal Error on Performing Segue

Tags: ios, swift, crash, segue, identifier

My iOS app is crashing when I run the following line of code after the push of a standard UIButton:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginAttempt", sender: self)
```

The segue identifier name is correct as I copied and pasted the name from the sidebar into the code. Upon remove the code the app stops crashing when the button is pressed.

The error I get is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1002544fc)
```

And in the Output box:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Have you named the segue `loginAttempt` from the storyboard?

Comment: If you mean the "Identifier" option found in the Attributes inspector, then yes. That's where I copied the name from into the code to ensure there were no spelling errors.

Comment: Have you dragged the segue from the view controller to the next view controller, or from the button to the next view controller?

Comment: I dragged the segue from the view controller to the next. Specifically I dragged it from the little yellow box with the tooltip of View Controller to the next.

Comment: Try dragging from the button to the next view controller to create a segue (no code). If this doesn't work, please show us the code around the segue

Comment: Strange, doesn't work... There is no other code being run when the button is pressed. The only code that was running was the segue. @GabrielJones

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your main.storyboard with the segue selected under attributes menu?

Comment: Here you go @GabrielJones http://i.imgur.com/Mx4WGxE.png

Comment: don't know what the problem is, can you give us the project files?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll set up a Dropbox link this afternoon when I'm home :)

Comment: @GabrielJones I seemed to have just fixed the problem by removing the segue and recreating it...very strange. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad your problem's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error is somewhere else but for clearity.

1)put breakpoint on seguing line and note is control is reaching to segue line.

Or

2) following put your segue for testing:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginAttempt", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
   if (segue.identifier == "loginAttempt") {
        print("Hi segue is working")
   }
}
```

if it prints line then segue is working .

Comment: Should this all go in ViewController.swift ?

Comment: Ok, so in the output box it is printing the message "Hi segue is working"...but still crashes. Have added a breakpoint on the initial line of code and it's making it to that point and stopping there.

Comment: its mean segue is calling . error is somewhere else while optional unwrapping. above code i gave you for testing . is segue is working. 
so, its clear error is somewhere else.

Comment: if you paste here code may we can help you out in finding optional error.

Comment: You want everything inside the ViewController.swift? There isn't a great deal but can do :)

Comment: you can paste related code where compiler is stopping basically .. from here to above few lines

Comment: `@IBAction func textField2(sender: UITextField) { if (progressView1.progress == 1) { button1.enabled = true } else { button1.enabled = false } } @IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) { self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginAttempt", sender: nil) } }`

Comment: Bit of a mess, sorry. Haven't quite figured out how to post code in comments lol

Comment: change    `sender:self`

Comment: Still crashing, there are no other errors or warning in the code either :/

Comment: there is no optional . nil found should somewhere else

Comment: Says something like that in the output box:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: understanding but there is no optional.. which line highlighted when xcode stops. click on all variables it will tell you at that time what was the value in it.

Comment: I added a breakpoint on the line causing problems, and there was supposedly an activity indicator with nil value. I removed that but still crashing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after many hours of frustration I found my own problem. Ultimately, the problem was that I had added new code in my ViewController class. The page I was segueing too had never been given a designated class and default to the ViewController class. When it tried to run the code for that class, the new view controller was missing elements found in the code and caused the crash.

I simply created a new class to give to the page that I was segueing too and everything worked fine again!

I'm not certain that that is your problem but I hope that at least helps a little bit with where the problem might be!